# C/preprocessor standard macro for OpenACC?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, openacc

In OpenMP we have `_OPENMP` macro defined (pretty much by any compiler I know--gcc, pgi, intel, ...) when we compile in OpenMP mode. Do we have similar "standard" macro defined when we compile in OpenACC mode (Cray/pgi/other compilers)?

Wirawan

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have a similar macro defined for openacc: _OPENACC.

```
2.2 Conditional Compilation

The _OPENACC macro name is defined to have a value yyyymm where yyyy is the year and
mm is the month designation of the version of the OpenACC directives supported by the
implementation. This macro must be defined by a compiler only when OpenACC directives
are enabled. The version described here is 201306.
```